# What does the annotation R mean here?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

My professor is talking about relations and he gave us this example.

$A=\mathbb{Z}$ and  $B=\mathbb{Z}$.

$R\subset A\times B$.

$aRb$ if and only if $a-b$ is even.

Some examples of subsets were given.

5R3, 3R5, and 6R4. This makes sense because a-b for all the values here are even and they are all contained in $\mathbb{Z}$.

The definition for the image is given by  $\{b\in  B:\exists a\in A:(a,b)\in R\}$. So why is the image  of 5R3, 3R5, and 6R4 B and not {3,5,4}. What am I not understanding about the notation of what R means?

Comment: $xRy$ is an abbreviation of $(x,y)\in R$.

Comment: $R$ is the set of ordered pairs where the first element comes from $A$ and the second element comes from $B$ (this is expressed by $R \subset A \times B$). People write $x R y$ as shorthand for $(x,y) \in R$ because commonly, when $R$ is regarded as a "relation" (as seems to be the case here), people use what is called "infix" notation (where the letter or notation for the relation is interposed between the elements of the ordered pair) to express it. For example if the relation $R$ is strict equality it looks weird to write $(3,3) \in =$ and we are more used to writing $3=3$.

Comment: Note that the definition of "image" in your amended question does not depend on any particular pair of elements. There's no defined notion of an image of a single ordered pair under the relation. The image is simply the set of second coordinates of things in the relation, i.e., the set of second coordinates that appear in the set $R$. (There's a $\mathbb{R}$ in your question that seems like it ought to be an $R$).

Comment: @leslie townes $R$ is not *the* set of (because of the definite article implicitly all) pairs $(a, b)$ but *a* set of such pairs, i.e. just a subset of $A \times B$.

Comment: @EikeSchulte it is too late for me to amend that comment but absolutely yes. And thank you,

Answer (score 1):

The relation $R$ is the set of *all* pairs $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a-b$ is even.  You're right that the image of the relation $\{(5,3),(3,5),(6,4)\}$  would be just $\{3,4,5\}$, but those are just *examples* of elements of $R$, not all of them.  There are many (infinitely!) more elements, such as $(0,0)$, $(-1,19)$, $(5,37)$, ...

In particular, notice that for any integer $b$ at all, $(b,b)$ will be an element of $R$, since $b-b=0$ is even.  This proves that $b$ is in the image of $R$, so the image of $R$ actually contains every integer.